# Weird UV artifacts in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv, artifacts

In preview render (with enabled RenderLayer) it looks ok:

[image: Right]

But in actual final render something strange happening with UV map:

[image: Wrong]

I tried to reunwrap mesh, change sample count but result is still the same
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Problem's solved! I've forgot about hidden array modifier, which is appeard in render and overlapped wall :)